# Set hue of image store in matrix

Tags: android, opencv, hue

I am trying to change the hue of image store in matrix. I got a hue channel using split() function but i am not able to change its hue. I am using the function set(Scalar scalar) to change its hue, but i don't see any change in image.

```
        Mat eyeball_HSV = new Mat();
        Mat dest = new Mat();       
        Mat eye = new Mat();

        eye = mRgba.submat(eye_template);

        List<Mat> hsv_channel = new ArrayList<Mat>();

           Imgproc.cvtColor(eye, eyeball_HSV, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 0);

          // get HSV channel 
        //hsv_channel[0] is hue
        //hsv_channel[1] is saturation
        //hsv_channel[2] is visibility
        Core.split(eyeball_HSV, hsv_channel);

        try
        {
             hsv_channel.get(0).setTo(new Scalar(145,25,45));
             Log.v(TAG, "Got the Channel!");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(TAG, "Didn't get any channel");
        }

        Imgproc.cvtColor(eyeball_HSV, dest, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(dest, eye, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the code

```
hsv_channel.get(0).setTo(new Scalar(145,25,45));
```

to

```
hsv_channel.get(0).setTo(new Scalar(145)); // whatever your value
```

hsv_channel.get(0) is single channel Mat so your Scalar value should be with single.

Edit:-

Yo can see the OpenCV camera preview example [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-1-camerapreview)

On Tutorial1Activity.java you can see a method

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
```

Add these lines on this method

```
       src = inputFrame.rgba();  
       Imgproc.cvtColor(src, hsv,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV );     
       Core.split(hsv, hsv_channel);
      // Imgproc.equalizeHist(hsv_channel.get(0), hsv_channel.get(0));
       hsv_channel.get(0).setTo(new Scalar(64));
       Core.merge(hsv_channel, hsv);
       Imgproc.cvtColor(hsv, src,Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB );     
       //return hsv_channel.get(0);
       return src;
```

Comment: I have a question??? If you want to change only sub(selected) part of image like in my case i have detect eye now i want to change its color. So should i change the whole image to HSV and then change that selected matrix hue or should i change only selected matrix to hsv and then change its hue.

Comment: You can use image roi and perform operation on selected part, like eye in your case

Comment: See the result I got for different hue values http://i44.tinypic.com/102wnys.png http://i40.tinypic.com/2a7sd5c.png http://i43.tinypic.com/2h3u42x.png

Comment: looking good but this is nothing happens when i change the hue using setTo(Scalar scalar)

Comment: Can you exactly specify which sample you are talking about. There are many sample in the sdk

Comment: Got to OpenCV-2.4.7-android-sdk/samples/tutorial-1-camerapreview

Comment: your really help me. Now i achieve what i was looking for from last 3-4 days

Comment: i was not merging channel back in hsv. i just added that now it working fine